# How to fully install LaTeX in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, latex

What is the equivalent to `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` on Fedora system?
I read it is `yum install texlive-scheme-full`. Am I correct?

Comment: FYI, I have had great success using the [direct TeX Live install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) on my Fedora system.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes. `dnf install texlive-scheme-full` (or `yum install texlive-scheme-full`, in older versions) is the way to go. While the installed packages are not fully equivalent the intention is the same.

As stated here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/44989/how-to-install-latex-for-fedora-19/ there are the following schemes:

```
texlive-scheme-basic : basic scheme (plain and latex)
texlive-scheme-context : ConTeXt scheme
texlive-scheme-full : full scheme (everything)
texlive-scheme-gust : GUST TeX Live scheme
texlive-scheme-medium : medium scheme (small + more packages and languages)
texlive-scheme-minimal : minimal scheme (plain only)
texlive-scheme-small : small scheme (basic + xetex, metapost, a few languages)
texlive-scheme-tetex : teTeX scheme (more than medium, but nowhere near full)
texlive-scheme-xml : XML scheme
```

and various collections (if you want some finer control over what you install):

```
texlive-collection-basic : Essential programs and files
texlive-collection-bibtexextra : BibTeX additional styles
texlive-collection-binextra : TeX auxiliary programs
texlive-collection-context : ConTeXt and packages
texlive-collection-fontsextra : Additional fonts
texlive-collection-fontsrecommended : Recommended fonts
texlive-collection-fontutils : Graphics and font utilities
texlive-collection-formatsextra : Additional formats
texlive-collection-games : Games typesetting
texlive-collection-genericextra : Generic additional packages
texlive-collection-genericrecommended : Generic recommended packages
texlive-collection-htmlxml : HTML/SGML/XML support
texlive-collection-humanities : Humanities packages
texlive-collection-langafrican : African scripts
texlive-collection-langarabic : Arabic
texlive-collection-langcjk : Chinese/Japanese/Korean
texlive-collection-langcyrillic : Cyrillic
texlive-collection-langczechslovak : Czech/Slovak
texlive-collection-langenglish : US and UK English
texlive-collection-langeuropean : Other European languages
texlive-collection-langfrench : French
texlive-collection-langgerman : German
texlive-collection-langgreek : Greek
texlive-collection-langindic : Indic scripts
texlive-collection-langitalian : Italian
texlive-collection-langother : Other languages
texlive-collection-langpolish : Polish
texlive-collection-langportuguese : Portuguese
texlive-collection-langspanish : Spanish
texlive-collection-latex : LaTeX fundamental packages
texlive-collection-latexextra : LaTeX additional packages
texlive-collection-latexrecommended : LaTeX recommended packages
texlive-collection-luatex : LuaTeX packages
texlive-collection-mathextra : Mathematics packages
texlive-collection-metapost : MetaPost and Metafont packages
texlive-collection-music : Music packages
texlive-collection-omega : Omega packages
texlive-collection-pictures : Graphics, pictures, diagrams
texlive-collection-plainextra : Plain TeX packages
texlive-collection-pstricks : PSTricks
texlive-collection-publishers : Publisher styles, theses, etc
texlive-collection-science : Natural and computer sciences
texlive-collection-xetex : XeTeX and packages
```

Comment: my intention is to use Latex to write reports (essentially) and other kind of documents in Portuguese. I want to have a suitable installation that allows me to create documents with images, tables, customized fonts, etc. Therefore, should I install the scheme-full or do you have a lightweight / more appropriate solution?

Comment: As long as disk space and bandwidth are sufficient I would go with the 'lazy' approach and install the full scheme. This will prevent you from wondering why a package is missing and figuring out where it is.

Comment: Pulls in 3,127 packages for me, in addition to what was installed with texlive. Be ready to have a cup of tea. But @jschlichtholz is right: it's still _way_ faster than tracking down a missing package from a cryptic error.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to use fedoras current package manager [dnf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(Dandified_Yum)) instead of yum.
Your installation command is then

```
sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full
```

The word `scheme` means that a set of latex packages is installed simultaneously. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/neurofedora/latex/

To see what is actually installed by the scheme just check out the dependency list

```
dnf deplist texlive-scheme-full
```

giving you an output like this

```
package: texlive-scheme-full-6:svn33790.0-42.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-base
   provider: texlive-base-7:20170520-42.fc28.x86_64
   provider: texlive-base-6:2016-42.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-basic
   provider: texlive-collection-basic-6:svn41149-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-bibtexextra
   provider: texlive-collection-bibtexextra-6:svn41332-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-binextra
   provider: texlive-collection-binextra-6:svn40690-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-context
   provider: texlive-collection-context-6:svn36190.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontsextra
   provider: texlive-collection-fontsextra-6:svn41166-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontsrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-fontsrecommended-6:svn35830.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontutils
   provider: texlive-collection-fontutils-6:svn37105.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-formatsextra
   provider: texlive-collection-formatsextra-6:svn33658.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-games
   provider: texlive-collection-games-6:svn36348.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-genericextra
   provider: texlive-collection-genericextra-6:svn39964-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-genericrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-genericrecommended-6:svn35655.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-htmlxml
   provider: texlive-collection-htmlxml-6:svn35743.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-humanities
   provider: texlive-collection-humanities-6:svn39438-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langafrican
   provider: texlive-collection-langafrican-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langarabic
   provider: texlive-collection-langarabic-6:svn40201-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langchinese
   provider: texlive-collection-langchinese-6:svn40728-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langcjk
   provider: texlive-collection-langcjk-6:svn37224.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langcyrillic
   provider: texlive-collection-langcyrillic-6:svn41167-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langczechslovak
   provider: texlive-collection-langczechslovak-6:svn32550.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langenglish
   provider: texlive-collection-langenglish-6:svn37500.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langeuropean
   provider: texlive-collection-langeuropean-6:svn39721-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langfrench
   provider: texlive-collection-langfrench-6:svn40375-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langgerman
   provider: texlive-collection-langgerman-6:svn40098-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langgreek
   provider: texlive-collection-langgreek-6:svn39121-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langindic
   provider: texlive-collection-langindic-6:svn35737.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langitalian
   provider: texlive-collection-langitalian-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langjapanese
   provider: texlive-collection-langjapanese-6:svn41002-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langkorean
   provider: texlive-collection-langkorean-6:svn33790.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langother
   provider: texlive-collection-langother-6:svn31014.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langpolish
   provider: texlive-collection-langpolish-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langportuguese
   provider: texlive-collection-langportuguese-6:svn30962.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langspanish
   provider: texlive-collection-langspanish-6:svn40587-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latex
   provider: texlive-collection-latex-6:svn41011-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latexextra
   provider: texlive-collection-latexextra-6:svn41415-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latexrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-latexrecommended-6:svn35765.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-luatex
   provider: texlive-collection-luatex-6:svn39902-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-mathextra
   provider: texlive-collection-mathextra-6:svn40076-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-metapost
   provider: texlive-collection-metapost-6:svn39729-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-music
   provider: texlive-collection-music-6:svn40561-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-omega
   provider: texlive-collection-omega-6:svn30388.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-pictures
   provider: texlive-collection-pictures-6:svn40656-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-plainextra
   provider: texlive-collection-plainextra-6:svn37156.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-pstricks
   provider: texlive-collection-pstricks-6:svn40724-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-publishers
   provider: texlive-collection-publishers-6:svn41372-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-science
   provider: texlive-collection-science-6:svn39074-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-xetex
   provider: texlive-collection-xetex-6:svn40404-52.20160520.fc28.noarch

package: texlive-scheme-full-6:svn33790.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-base
   provider: texlive-base-7:20170520-42.fc28.x86_64
   provider: texlive-base-6:2016-42.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-basic
   provider: texlive-collection-basic-6:svn41149-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-bibtexextra
   provider: texlive-collection-bibtexextra-6:svn41332-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-binextra
   provider: texlive-collection-binextra-6:svn40690-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-context
   provider: texlive-collection-context-6:svn36190.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontsextra
   provider: texlive-collection-fontsextra-6:svn41166-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontsrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-fontsrecommended-6:svn35830.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-fontutils
   provider: texlive-collection-fontutils-6:svn37105.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-formatsextra
   provider: texlive-collection-formatsextra-6:svn33658.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-games
   provider: texlive-collection-games-6:svn36348.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-genericextra
   provider: texlive-collection-genericextra-6:svn39964-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-genericrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-genericrecommended-6:svn35655.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-htmlxml
   provider: texlive-collection-htmlxml-6:svn35743.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-humanities
   provider: texlive-collection-humanities-6:svn39438-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langafrican
   provider: texlive-collection-langafrican-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langarabic
   provider: texlive-collection-langarabic-6:svn40201-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langchinese
   provider: texlive-collection-langchinese-6:svn40728-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langcjk
   provider: texlive-collection-langcjk-6:svn37224.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langcyrillic
   provider: texlive-collection-langcyrillic-6:svn41167-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langczechslovak
   provider: texlive-collection-langczechslovak-6:svn32550.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langenglish
   provider: texlive-collection-langenglish-6:svn37500.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langeuropean
   provider: texlive-collection-langeuropean-6:svn39721-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langfrench
   provider: texlive-collection-langfrench-6:svn40375-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langgerman
   provider: texlive-collection-langgerman-6:svn40098-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langgreek
   provider: texlive-collection-langgreek-6:svn39121-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langindic
   provider: texlive-collection-langindic-6:svn35737.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langitalian
   provider: texlive-collection-langitalian-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langjapanese
   provider: texlive-collection-langjapanese-6:svn41002-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langkorean
   provider: texlive-collection-langkorean-6:svn33790.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langother
   provider: texlive-collection-langother-6:svn31014.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langpolish
   provider: texlive-collection-langpolish-6:svn30372.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langportuguese
   provider: texlive-collection-langportuguese-6:svn30962.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-langspanish
   provider: texlive-collection-langspanish-6:svn40587-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latex
   provider: texlive-collection-latex-6:svn41011-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latexextra
   provider: texlive-collection-latexextra-6:svn41415-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-latexrecommended
   provider: texlive-collection-latexrecommended-6:svn35765.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-luatex
   provider: texlive-collection-luatex-6:svn39902-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-mathextra
   provider: texlive-collection-mathextra-6:svn40076-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-metapost
   provider: texlive-collection-metapost-6:svn39729-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-music
   provider: texlive-collection-music-6:svn40561-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-omega
   provider: texlive-collection-omega-6:svn30388.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-pictures
   provider: texlive-collection-pictures-6:svn40656-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-plainextra
   provider: texlive-collection-plainextra-6:svn37156.0-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-pstricks
   provider: texlive-collection-pstricks-6:svn40724-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-publishers
   provider: texlive-collection-publishers-6:svn41372-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-science
   provider: texlive-collection-science-6:svn39074-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
  dependency: texlive-collection-xetex
   provider: texlive-collection-xetex-6:svn40404-52.20160520.fc28.noarch
```

Comment: To be fair, in recent versions of Fedora, `yum` is a symlink to dnf `lrwxrwxrwx@ 5 root 19 Oct  2020 /usr/bin/yum -> dnf-3`

Answer (score 5):

To get latex:

```
yum -y install texlive
```

is not enough.

https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/350f86611bc012a5c1c6  has a decent approach

```
yum -y install texlive texlive-latex texlive-xetex
yum -y install texlive-collection-latex
yum -y install texlive-collection-latexrecommended
yum -y install texlive-xetex-def
yum -y install texlive-collection-xetex
```

Only if needed:

```
yum -y install texlive-collection-latexextra
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dnf -y reinstall texlive*
```